# Convert isoformat to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a problem with converting isoformat to datetime.
I have this:

```py
[{'timex-value': '2019-W32T15:00', 'start': 18, 'end': 31, 'text': '3pm next week', 'type': 'TIME', 'value': '2019-W32T15:00'}]
```

How can I convert '2019-W32T15:00' to datetime format in python?

Comment: Maybe I just don't know my time formats, but how exactly does this format work?

Comment: is W32 the 32nd week?

Comment: what are the roles of `start`, `end` (and `text`) ?

Comment: As I understand, 'W32T15:30' mean  32th week of year. Maybe it is 2019-Aug-06 15:00.

Comment: Specifying a week though you then need the day of that week to get a datetime.

Comment: I just want convert 'timex-value'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a date time object you would want something like this. However you you will not get a the correct answer because you do not have a day of the week.

```
import date time as dt
dt.datetime.strptime('2019-W32T15:00','%Y-W%WT%H:%M')
```

If you want a successful conversion to a date time then specify the first day of that week by adding a 1 to the `timex-value` string.

```
import date time as dt
dt.datetime.strptime('2019-W32T15:00'+'-1','%Y-W%WT%H:%M-%w')
```

Result: `datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 12, 15, 0)`